# elastic search admin API preparePutIndexedScript does not exist anymore

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to use exactly this method on the adminClusterApi,

```
client.preparePutIndexedScript()
                         .setScriptLang("painless")
                         .setId("script1")
                         .setSource("script", "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value")
                         .execute()
                         .actionGet();
```

I tried the following elastic-search-client version.
* 5.6.1
* 5.3.1
* 5.3.3

but sadly I can't find this method and even the preparePutIndexedScript on the Java Api anymore, does someone have any idea?

according with the documentation this class still exists -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/indexed-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

> All the methods related to interacting with indexed scripts have been
>   removed. The Java API methods for interacting with stored scripts have
>   been added under ClusterAdminClient class. The sugar methods that used
>   to exist on the indexed scripts API methods don’t exist on the methods
>   for stored scripts. The only way to provide scripts is by using
>   BytesReference implementation, if a string needs to be provided the
>   BytesArray class should be used.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_scripting.html#_indexed_scripts_java_apis

would be nice though if the other documentation part that i mentioned would be upgrade was a bit hard to find this.